# magento 2 REST API for cutom collection based on store code

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

magento 2 REST API for custom collection based on store code how to pass store id

**rest/store_code/V1/banners**

**rest/ar/V1/banners**

different store having different banners so how to get the banners collection  based on store code

Comment: Ok. What is the question?